# Create a .dll file of java from the .net dll

Tags: java, .net, dll, porting

I am really struck at this point.

I have a .dll that is written .net and which is created using SWIG(http://www.swig.org/).
No my goal is to use the dll in java.

So my questions are

1. Can I use the dll file directly? i.e. is the dll file independent on the language in which it is written??

if not , What is the best way to re-write/port the dll to java?

1. How can i create Export functions that i can use directly from my java code after initializing this dll.

Thanks for the try!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is using [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/). I have used [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to call windows API (not .net though).  You may check some [examples](https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/master/contrib).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately someone already suggested this and deleted it, but it is a valid solution and probably the best one.

1. Use [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) to create an interface from your Java code to native
2. Using the [.NET hosting API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404385.aspx) load the .NET Runtime into your Java process
3. The .NET Runtime can now be used to load your .NET DLL
4. From your Java code call into your [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) layer in native and then into the .NET DLL